# Search string in files in cron jobs unix

Tags: unix, search, cron, grep, aix

I need to search a string '025' in a list of cron jobs.  I need the output of all the files that contain this string.  I am not too sure which directory has the list of all these jobs as I just access them by crontab -l or crontab -e.  I tried grep but not sure how to check all jobs that are scheduled in cron?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
 grep -r 025 /var/spool/cron
```

?

Dunno if the PATH `/var/spool/cron` is accurate for `AIX`, but you get the idea...

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like that, if I want to output the results to a text file do I redirect like this: grep -r 025 /var/spool/cron > 025.txt